# Mathematical term for finding the variance of the euclidean distance between two matrices of the same dimension?

Tags: variance, euclidean

[image]

Is there any mathematical term for carrying out this procedure. I am finding the euclidean distance between the rows of the matrices by treating them as individual vector. Then I get a single vector A consisting of the euclidean distance between corresponding rows. I then find the variance of A. I want to know whether there is any mathematical term for this operation. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: what do you mean by euclidian distance between matrices?

Comment: Whatever this might mean, it sounds like you are treating the matrices merely as vectors.  Why should there be any special mathematical term for such a variance?  If you're looking to research work on this, then, look at materials related to variances of distances or Euclidean distances and forget about the incidental and irrelevant fact that your components are written down in rectangles on the page rather than as rows of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Variance of the Frobenius norm of the difference of matrices

Comment: I'd call it the 2-norm.  I despise that mathematics nomenclature, as a second (or third) language, is comprised mostly with the last names of old, dead, men.  That, as the foundation for a language, is a bad start.  Unless the man is known, the word is essentially meaningless.